# Need help with WCF design

Tags: wcf, service, esb

I have been tasked with creating a set of web services.  We are a Microsoft shop, so I will be using WCF for this project.  There is an interesting design consideration that I haven't been able to figure out a solution for yet.  I'll try to explain it with an example:

My WCF service exposes a method named Foo().

10 different users call Foo() at roughly the same time.

I have 5 special resources called R1, R2, R3, R4, and R5.  We don't really need to know what the resource is, other than the fact that a particular resource can only be in use by one caller at a time.

Foo() is responsible to performing an action using one of these special resources.  So, in a round-robin fashion, Foo() needs to find a resource that is not in use.  If no resources are available, it must wait for one to be freed up.

At first, this seems like an easy task.  I could maybe create a singleton that keeps track of which resources are currently in use.  The big problem is the fact that I need this solution to be viable in a web farm scenario.

I'm sure there is a good solution to this problem, but I've just never run across this scenario before.  I need some sort of resource tracker / provider that can be shared between multiple WCF hosts.

Any ideas from the architects out there would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Create another central service which only the web services know about. This service takes on the role of the resource manager.

All of the web services in the farm will communicate with this central service to query for resource availability and to "check out" and "check in" resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could track the resource usage in a database table, which all the servers on the farm could access.

Each resource would have a record in the database, with fields that indicate whether (or since when) it is in use.  You could get fancy and implement a timeout feature as well.

For troubleshooting purposes, you could also record who is using the resource.

If you record when each resource is being used (in another table), you would be able to verify that your round-robin is functioning as you expect, decide whether you should add more copies of the resource, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of approaches to solving this problem, each with their own costs and benefits. For example:

- Using MSMQ to queue all requests, worker processes pull messages from the queue, pass to Rn and post responses back to a response queue for Foo to dispatch back to the appropriate caller.
- Using an in-memory or locally persisted message dispatcher to send the next request to an on-box service (e.g. via Named Pipes for perf) based upon some distribution algorithm of your choice.

etc.

Alas, you don't indicate whether your requests have to survive power outages, if they need to be transactionally aware, whether the callers are also WCF, how quickly these calls will be received, how long it takes for Rn to return with results, etc.

Whichever solution you choose, I strongly encourage you to split your call to Foo() into a RequestFoo() and GetFooResponse() pair or implement a WCF callback hosted by the caller to receive results asynchronously.

If you do NOT do this, you're likely to find that your entire system will grind to a halt the second traffic exceeds your resources' abilty to satisfy the workload.